# Gallery won't show pictures using Intent in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I have tried the same code in my other project and is working perfectly fine. My problem here is that when I click **CHOOSE PHOTO** and it should open the gallery to choose pictures to upload. However, mine is showing like this:

[image]

The other app that I have is showing picture in the gallery. Take a look:

[image]

I have already double checked and I can see that I have used the correct permission with this code.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.devcash">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".WhyDevcash"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".HelpCenterEmployees" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
            android:value="barcode" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

This is a snippet of my MainActivity

```
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 100;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_employee);

        choosephoto = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.empchoosephoto);
        choosephoto.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int sid = v.getId();

        switch (sid){
            case R.id.empchoosephoto:
                Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(gallery, PICK_IMAGE);
                break;
        }
     }

 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode!=0){
            if(data!=null){
                empimageUri = data.getData();
                empimage.setImageURI(empimageUri);
            }
        }
    }
```

Can you please tell me what am I missing with this one?

Comment: try setting your action to `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` and your type to `image/*` in your intent

Comment: Sorry, how do I set the type?

Comment: Intent gallery = new Intent()

Comment: gallery.setType and setAction

Comment: Ok. I'll try that

Comment: let me know if it works, hopefully it does :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);
```

try this, your intent for picking images was probably formed incorrectly

Comment: Tried this and now the gallery won't open :(

Comment: i've updated it now, that really should work though